# Is there a pager that stops on form feeds?

Tags: pager

Is there a pager that stops on form feeds?

When I'm reading RFCs, I can read them like this:

```
$ less -z57 rfc748.txt
```

This will keep the pager lined up with the pages, but this is a bit of a hack, and when I do a search I'd prefer it to line up the screen with the page boundaries.  The page boundaries are marked with form feeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`more` does this [by default](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_%28command%29):

> Once `more` has obtained input, it displays as much as can fit on the current screen and waits for user input to advance, with the exception that a form feed (^L) will also cause `more` to wait at that line, regardless of the amount of text on the screen.

To disable this behavior, use the `-l` option.

Comment: Hm, I was hoping for a pager that also had other basic features I take for granted, like a key to go to the top of the file or the ability to search backwards.